# How to declare variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I try to declare a variable in a code like this:

```
DECLARE
    p_country VARCHAR;
 p_country : = ''; 
SELECT p_country;
```

But it's doesn't work:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VARCHAR"
> LINE 2:  p_country VARCHAR;
> ```

Can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Please give more data about your problem

Comment: It's better to write like this one:
DECLARE
 p_country VARCHAR;
 p_country : = '';
 SELECT p_country;

Comment: What's wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new setting in postgresql.conf for custom_variable_classes:

```
custom_variable_classes = 'var'
```

Reload the config, you now have the variable "var" available in all your databases.

To create the variable p_country, just use SET:

```
SET var.p_country = 'US';
SELECT current_setting('var.p_country') AS p_country;
```

It's not a beauty, but it works.

Comment: It's interesting. But the poblem is that I make queries to the remote server. I don't think I'll be allowed to edit postgresql.conf.

Comment: You could ask them to add this in the configuration, it aint rocket science. You could also use a temp table to put your variables in.

Answer (score 3):

Within a PL/pgSQL function you can declare variables like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION identifier (arguments) RETURNS type AS '
  DECLARE

     -- Declare an integer.
    subject_id INTEGER;

     -- Declare a variable length character.
    book_title VARCHAR(10);

      -- Declare a floating point number.
    book_price FLOAT;

  BEGIN
    statements
  END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Source: http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/x19832

Comment: But I want to declare a variable out of the function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**PL/pgSQL**

I had the same problem as you. Turns out, the DECLARE statement is something from an entire different language PL/pgSQL. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql.html

**PostgreSQL**

To achieve this with PostgreSQL, you can do the following:

```
WITH myconstants (p_country) as (
   values ('')
)

SELECT p_country FROM myconstants;
```